# Set ContentDialog to show on bottom of page in UWP

Tags: xaml, dialog, uwp, windows-phone

I have several ContentDialogs in a RelativeLayout and want them to appear or have the the vertical alignment to "bottom". But it seems that no matter what I try the dialogs always appear on the top of the screen. 
This is how they look now

[image]

Any ideas?
Here is a xaml code snippet:

```
    <RelativePanel Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Page}" >
                <ContentDialog x:Name="EntrepriseDialog"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               Title="Vælg entreprise"
                           PrimaryButtonText=""
                        IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBoxAgree, Mode=OneWay}"
                        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="30,194,-71,-194">
                    <ListView Name="ListEntreprises" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionChanged="ListEntreprises_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ContentDialog>
                <ContentDialog x:Name="SaveChooseDialog"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Title=""
                           PrimaryButtonText=""

                        IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBoxAgree, Mode=OneWay}"
                        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="30,148,-71,-148">
                    <ListBox Name="ListBoxSaveMode"  SelectionChanged="ListBoxSaveMode_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Name="TxtLocally" Text="Gem lokalt"/>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Name="TxtServer" Text="Gem på server"/>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Name="TxtCancel" Text="Annullér"/>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </ContentDialog>
                <ContentDialog x:Name="AddPictureDialog"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Title=""
                           PrimaryButtonText=""

                        IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBoxAgree, Mode=OneWay}"
                        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="30,142,-71,-142">
                    <ListBox Name="ListBoxAddPicture"  SelectionChanged="ListBoxAddPicture_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Name="TxtFromCamera" Text="Tag et nyt"/>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>
                            <TextBlock Name="TxtFromStorage" Text="Vælg fra kamerarulle"/>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </ContentDialog>
            </RelativePanel>
```

**EDIT: XAML for entire Page**

```
<Page
Name="Page"
x:Class="...Pages.Documentation.DocumentationCreatePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:...Pages.Documentation"
xmlns:userControl="using:...Pages.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="#8FBC3E">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="/Assets/Images/mainBg.png" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Height="40" Background="#8FBC3E" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Name="BtnBack" Click="BtnBack_Click" Margin="20 0 20 0" >
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBlock  FontSize="20" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE0A6;"></TextBlock>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Name="TxtTitle" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <userControl:SyncDataControl></userControl:SyncDataControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Name="StackPanel">
        <ProgressRing Name="SaveProgressRing" IsActive="False" Foreground="#8FBC3E" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="152,239,87,321"  />
        <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView Name="ListViewDocumentationItems" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" SelectionChanged="ListViewDocumentationItems_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel Padding="0 0 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="5 0 5 0"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Run FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 20 0">
                                    <Run FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <Image Width="15" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Assets/Images/rightarrow.png" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <TextBlock Name="TxtDocDesc" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Height="53" />
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel Name="PicturePanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15 0 15 0" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Name="BtnSave" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="25" Click="BtnSave_Click" Background="#8FBC3E" Foreground="White" Height="60" Content="Gem" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5 5 5 5"/>
        <RelativePanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
            <ContentDialog x:Name="EntrepriseDialog" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                        RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                               Title="Vælg entreprise"
                           PrimaryButtonText=""
                        IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBoxAgree, Mode=OneWay}"
                        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}" >
                <ListView Name="ListEntreprises" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectionChanged="ListEntreprises_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,1"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock>
                            <Run FontSize="15" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Id}"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ContentDialog>
            <ContentDialog x:Name="SaveChooseDialog"
                        RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                        Title=""
                           PrimaryButtonText=""
                        IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBoxAgree, Mode=OneWay}"
                        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}">
                <ListBox Name="ListBoxSaveMode"  SelectionChanged="ListBoxSaveMode_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtLocally" Text="Gem lokalt"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtServer" Text="Gem på server"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtCancel" Text="Annullér"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </ContentDialog>
            <ContentDialog x:Name="AddPictureDialog"
                        Title=""
                        PrimaryButtonText=""
                        IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBoxAgree, Mode=OneWay}"
                        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}" >
                <ListBox Name="ListBoxAddPicture" SelectionChanged="ListBoxAddPicture_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtFromCamera" Text="Tag et nyt"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock Name="TxtFromStorage" Text="Vælg fra kamerarulle"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </ContentDialog>
            <ContentDialog x:Name="DialogDownloadProgress" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Title=""
                   MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=pageRoot}">
                <StackPanel Padding="0,50">
                    <TextBlock Name="ProgressTitle" Text="Test test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0 0 0 20"/>
                    <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBarDownload" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsEnabled="True"></ProgressBar>
                </StackPanel>
            </ContentDialog>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've awarded it now. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the positioning of ContentDialog instances is not in the hands of the developer, at least not without custom versions of it. Afaik the OS will decide where to place the dialog for you.

See here for more information:

http://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2015/windows-10-xaml-tips-messagedialog-and-contentdialog

So if positioning of the dialog is critical then you might have to create a custom control.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but no luck. It seems that it always defaults to top no matter what I do. I've tried to hardcode a height for the RelativePanel just to be sure, but that didn't change anything eiher :/

Comment: Putting the dialogs in the grid and setting their Grid.Row property to something high gives me the same results too.

Comment: Can you please post the entire page? It seems something outside of the RelativePanel is causing the issue.

Comment: I have edited the question and the whole page is in the bottom. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the effort! At least I have an answer to my question now :-)